# Log Exceptions with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, frameworks, entity

I want to log the query which is generated by entity framework and failed.

How to achieve that?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can run SQL Profiler to see the generated query. See if it helps.

Comment: I want to log the errors in DB and email them at runtime when they occur so that someone can look at the query and fix it asap.

Comment: In try catch how can I get the sql query which is throwing the error